# EF Core Filtered Include with Select

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Sorry for my English.

I ran into a mistake with EF Core 5.0.9 when is use Filtered Include and Select in same time and i don't know is a bug or feature. :)

```
return await _dbContext.User
    .Where(u => !u.TOROLT)
    .Where(u => ids.Contains(u.Id))
    .Include(u => u.EventUsers.Where(eu => !eu.TOROLT && eu.EventId == eventId))
    .Select(u => new UserDropDownDtoWithInviteData
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        EventUserId = u.EventUsers.First().Id,
        IsCelebrated = u.EventUsers.First().IsCelebrated,
        IsEventAdmin = u.EventUsers.First().IsEventAdmin,
        IsInviteAccepted = u.EventUsers.First().IsInviteAccepted,
        IsInvited = u.EventUsers.First().IsInvited,
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

In this time the first elements is select is not from filtered include just from a normal include. SQL Script from Profiler:

```
SELECT
[u].[Id],
[u].[FirstName],
[u].[LastName],
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [e].[Id]
    FROM [dbo].[EventUser] AS [e]
    WHERE [u].[Id] = [e].[UserId]) AS [EventUserId],
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [e0].[IsCelebrated]
    FROM [dbo].[EventUser] AS [e0]
    WHERE [u].[Id] = [e0].[UserId]) AS [IsCelebrated],
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [e1].[IsEventAdmin]
    FROM [dbo].[EventUser] AS [e1]
    WHERE [u].[Id] = [e1].[UserId]) AS [IsEventAdmin],
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [e2].[IsInviteAccepted]
    FROM [dbo].[EventUser] AS [e2]
    WHERE [u].[Id] = [e2].[UserId]) AS [IsInviteAccepted],
(
    SELECT TOP(1) [e3].[IsInvited]
    FROM [dbo].[EventUser] AS [e3]
    WHERE [u].[Id] = [e3].[UserId]) AS [IsInvited]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [u]
WHERE ([u].[TOROLT] <> CAST(1 AS bit))
    AND [u].[Id] IN (2, 1, 3, 4, 5)
```

But if is separate filtered include and select, than it work's fine, but this select complete record and not the part of him from database:

```
var a = await _dbContext.User
    .Where(u => !u.TOROLT)
    .Where(u => ids.Contains(u.Id))
    .Include(u => u.EventUsers.Where(eu => !eu.TOROLT && eu.EventId == eventId))
.ToListAsync();
return a.Select(u => new UserDropDownDtoWithInviteData
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        EventUserId = u.EventUsers.First().Id,
        IsCelebrated = u.EventUsers.First().IsCelebrated,
        IsEventAdmin = u.EventUsers.First().IsEventAdmin,
        IsInviteAccepted = u.EventUsers.First().IsInviteAccepted,
        IsInvited = u.EventUsers.First().IsInvited,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Any idea why is this, and how can i solve solve this?

THX

Comment: Just bookmarked the question... could you extract the SQL Script from @Svyatoslav Danyliv query ? I just really curious what that would be... I guess that would equivelent to `.Include(u => u.EventUsers.FirstOrDefault(eu => !eu.TOROLT && eu.EventId == eventId))`... hope it will, I personally favor the chaining syntax than query style (XD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Include` is completely ignored if you have custom projection `Select`, so your filter will be also ignored. It is not a bug, `Include` works only when you get whole entity from query.

Anyway consider to rewrite your query:

```cs
var query = 
    from u in _dbContext.User
    where !u.TOROLT && ids.Contains(u.Id)
    from eu in u.EventUsers.Where(eu => !eu.TOROLT && eu.EventId == eventId)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new UserDropDownDtoWithInviteData
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        FirstName = u.FirstName,
        LastName = u.LastName,
        EventUserId = eu.Id,
        IsCelebrated = eu.IsCelebrated,
        IsEventAdmin = eu.IsEventAdmin,
        IsInviteAccepted = eu.IsInviteAccepted,
        IsInvited = eu.IsInvited,
    };

var result = await query.ToListAsync();
```